# Jquery / Ajax is requesting multiple request once submit button is clicked! Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm handling my form with jquery/ajax and it's data is process by PHP. Now when I click on **submit** button it's showing me multiple request in console log. It's should be show only one request once I clicked on **submit** button. Why ti's happening?

**html button:**

```
<input type="button" value="Update Document(s)" class="submit" id="upload"/>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
<script>
$('body').on('click', '#upload', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);
    var cid=$('#cdid_hidden').val();
    $("#upload-image").show();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'editContactDetails2.php',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            return myXhr;
    },

    success: function(data){                    
        //getDetails(cid);  
        $("#upload-image").hide(); //hide loading         
         $("#success").html(data);
        document.getElementById("all_contact_details").reset();         
    },

    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false

    });
});    
</script>
```

**Multiple request image:**

[image]

Comment: Is $("#success") populating several times too?

Comment: @ADASein No only one time.

Comment: It seems to me that if you're getting just one response then you aren't sending multiple requests. Weird.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me:

```
 event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

just keep this after button is pressed or use:

```
$("....").unbind().click(function(){

});
```